# My button doesn't seem to work with MVC controller, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to make my Save button update a string in db. For some reason it doesn't work.

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateTemplateBody(TemplateViewModel data)
{
    templateService.UpdateTemplateBody(data.Id, data.Html);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "TemplateEditor", new { id = data.Id });
}
```

Html from view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateTemplateBody", "TemplateList"))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Html, new { id = "Editor" })

    <br />
    <input class="btn btn-default" id="save" type="button" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: change type="button"  to type="submit"

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. Feel kind of stupid now, should have seen that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<input type="button" />`

Use: `<input type="submit" />`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateTemplateBody", "TemplateList"))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Html, new { id = "Editor" })

    <br />
    <input class="btn btn-default" id="save" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Also make sure your Controller Name is Correct (`TemplateListController`) in:

```
Html.BeginForm("UpdateTemplateBody", "TemplateList")
```